# How to minimize a linear function to the constraints, my confusion arises from the notation?

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, graph-algorithm, linear-programming

So essentially I understand how to minimize/maximize a linear function when I am given it in the form such as y = mx + b.

But the problem involves a flow network and linear programming, and this is really what is confusing me. I would seriously appreciate any clarification! And no, this is not a homework problem, but an optional exercise. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This is the LP for min-cost bipartite [fractional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_matching). This LP happens to be totally unimodular, so there is an integer solution that is as good as all fractional matchings, and you can find it with the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). Did you have a specific question?

Comment: I am just having trouble putting/visualizing this in context of a simple x,y graph, as I can definitely solve it once it I can see it in that form. Is there any way that I can reduce this problem so it is in something reminiscent of y=mx + b?

Comment: Also, you mentioned the Hungarian algorithm, which is something that was not taught to us. I am under the impression that our professor wants us to be able to solve such problems on our own.  @DavidEisenstat

Comment: The vector x is |E|-dimension so for nontrivial problems you can't draw a reasonable graph.

Answer (score -1):

The vector x is |E|-dimension, so I am thinking for nontrivial problems you cant even draw one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).